# How to export 2 week's worth of posts

Tags: sql, export, posts

I need to export the last two week's worth of blog posts from one site into another site, including all meta data and post author info.

Is there a good SQL statement to do this, or a plugin that will help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native import/export tool can do most of this, though I don't think it will grab all the author profile information (not sure on that - I know it doesn't bring over passwords, but it might bring the rest). In the WP admin panel go to Tools > Export and walk through the various option screens. Best of luck!

Comment: I guess they have improved that since the last time I've looked. Any thoughts as to if it preserves what the permalink should be? I want to ensure an almost exact replication, including URLS.

Comment: Yes, I believe it preserves the slug/permalink, though it will obey the settings of the new site. In other words if the old site used /%month%/%postname% and the new one uses /%month%/%day%/%postname% it will obey the new permalink structure. But the postname / slug will remain the same.